# Compute transition frequency matrix between values in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'])
```

and I'm trying to compute the transition frequencies between the values so that the output dataframe should look like this:

```
 State    A    B    C
 A        0    1    0
 B        0    2    1
 C        1    0    0
```

what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) between the series and the [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) of it:

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'])

print (pd.crosstab(s, s.shift(-1)))
col_0  A  B  C
row_0         
A      0  1  0
B      0  2  1
C      1  0  0
```

and if you want to remove the name of the axis you can use `rename_axis`:

```
pd.crosstab(s, s.shift(-1)).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
   A  B  C
A  0  1  0
B  0  2  1
C  1  0  0
```

Comment: That was really simple and clear. Thank you so much!